# Write the equation of a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> Write the equation of the line which is perpendicular to the red line graphed at the point $P(x,2)$.
>   [image]

I started with finding the equation of the red line using $y=a+bx$:
$$0=a+b(-6)$$
$$-3=a+b(0)$$
Which gives $a=-3$ and $b=-\frac12$. Therefore the equation of the original line is $y=-3-\frac x2$. Then what should I do?

Comment: @suomynonA "at the point $P(x,2)$."

Comment: yes, just saw it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that, the product of the slopes of this line and the line  perpendicular to this gives $-1$. since  comparison with $y=mx+c$, gives the slope of this line equals $-\frac12$, the slope of the line perpendicular is $2$.

So, 
 $$y= 2x+c.$$

Now, in the original line to find $x$ such that $y=2$, gives
$x=-10$.
So, for the new line to pass through this, $(-10,2)$ gives

$$c=22$$

line is $y=2x+22$

Answer (score 2):

Having obtained the line's equation, note that its slope is $-\frac12$. For a line with slope $m$, any perpendicular line will have slope $-\frac1m$, so the line to be found must have slope $-\frac1{-\frac12}=2$.

Furthermore, we are told that the point of intersection has $y=2$. Substituting this into the *first* line's equation, we get $x=-10$, i.e. $P=(-10,2)$. Then the $c$ in the equation of the perpendicular line $y=mx+c$ satisfies $2=-10\cdot2+c$, from which we get $c=22$.

Therefore the perpendicular line's equation is $y=2x+22$.